# For responsive web design what devices or resolutions needs to keep in mind?

Tags: html, css

I am about to start diving into Responsive Web Design. I am wondering what resolutions needs to take care of while designing the website.

Comment: Anyone else out there find it ironic that now, years after we told each other to stop worrying about 800-pixel monitors, we're falling over ourselves to deal with 320-pixel smartphones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site [mediaquerie.es](http://mediaqueri.es/about/), which portrais examples of sites with a good use of responsive designs, works with the following resolutions:

**Smartphone**

```
320px
```

**Tablet**

```
768px
```

**Netbook**

```
1024px
```

**Desktop**

```
1600px
```

Also, Quirktools has a tool to [test a site in different resolutions](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/).

Limiting somehow the amount of resolutions you are working with makes for a better workflow.
Also, it is better to use **liquid responsive designs** (like the [1149 CSS Grid](http://cssgrid.net/)) which will scale right with any viewport width.

Webdesigner Depot has a [list of available resources on responsive design](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/09/the-ultimate-responsive-web-design-roundup/).

Answer (score 0):

All of them -- every smartphone is different, although 320-pixel width (narrow orientation) seems to be the lowest.